# Binomial test to establish a pass criterion

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, binomial-distribution, control-group

I'm sorry for the following -probably- stupid question.
I'm performing a psychological experiment and I have no idea about how to establish how many control items one has to pass to be included. My professor told me to use a binomial test. I have 12 trials in total, and in each one the probability of success is 1/3 (since there are three options among which it is possible to choose, and only one is the correct one). How can I do this with R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the binomial density function (`dbinom` in R) to determine the probability of a specific outcome given a total number of trials $n=12$ and their independent success probabilities $p=1/3$ assuming the person is guessing. The curve on the left gives the probability of each number of successes under this assumption:

[image: binomial curves]

Also relevant for determining how probable a result is under these assumptions is the (complementary) cumulative density `pbinom`, shown on the right. You can see that guessing will result in about one in three (36.8% to be exact) experiments getting 4 successes or fewer, whereas it's much rarer for those to get at least 6 or 7 options correct.

The only thing missing is then for you to decide how confident you want to be that someone isn't guessing. If one in three is enough then you might let anyone that gets at least 4 options correct pass. It's more common in statistics to put something like 5% as 'a low probability', you'd need at least 7 options correct for there to be at most that much chance to get that result if the person is guessing.

The quantile function `qbinom` can tell you the cumulative probability of a given outcome - it is the inverse of the cumulative density function. Specifically, the cumulative density tells you how likely an outcome (or less/more) is, and the quantile function tells you which outcome has a specific cumulative probability.

R code is shown below:

```r
n <- 12    ## Number of trials
p <- 1/3   ## Probability of success if guessing

x <- 0:n   ## Range of possible outcomes

## Density
plot(x, dbinom(x, n, p))

## 1 - Cumulative density
plot(x, pbinom(x, n, p, lower.tail = FALSE))

## What outcome has at most 5% (one-sided) probability of occurring here?
qbinom(.95, n, p)
> 7
```

Comment: I understand. However, my doubt was about the correct R function to use, since performing binom.test the p value is not <0.05 with 7. More clearly, while > qbinom(.95,12,1/3) gives [1] 7, the function binom.test(7, 12, 1/3, alternative="greater", conf.level = 0.95) gives the following: Exact binomial test

data:  7 and 12
number of successes = 7, number of trials = 12, p-value = 0.06645
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is greater than 0.3333333
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3152378 1.0000000
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.5833333

Comment: @Katherine You're right, this is due to the discrete nature of the distribution. Strictly speaking $P(X\ge 8)=0.0188$ is the outcome that gets you below 5% under these assumptions, though the gap between 7 and 8 successes spans the exact threshold of 5%. On the other hand, $P(X\ge 7)=0.066$ as you calculated, so accepting 7 successes will lead to more than 5% of guessers getting past. You'll have to choose between letting that happen or *not* passing a few unlucky non-guessers that only got 7/12 (with the additional confidence that <2% of those passed were guessing under your assumptions).

Comment: Thank you again for the explanation! I was confused but now everything is clear. So to speak, there is always a margin of choice.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who randomly guesses, the number of successes in 12 trials is $X \sim \text{Binomial}(12, 1/3)$.

One possible setup: You can use [R functions](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Binomial.html) to find a number $q$ such that $P(X > q) < 0.05$. Then you can establish a requirement that a person must pass $> q$ questions in order to be included in the study. This ensures that $\ge 95\%$ of random guessers will not enter the study.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten a couple of answers that are statistical in nature, showing how to model things with a binomial distribution and eliminate a lot of people who randomly guess. If that's what you want, fine.

But I question whether that's really what you want, even if your professor said so. OK, maybe you just have to please your professor. But ... I would look at this from a substantive rather than a statistical point of view.

On a lot of tests you take in school, a passing grade is 70 (or some other number). This isn't based on what some random guesser would get, it's based on what the professor thinks a student should know. Similarly on many psychological tests.

I would try to do that here.